# JQM Listview data-filter doesn't work on iphone or simulator

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, filter, cordova

I have a listview with the data-filter enabled. The listitems are loaded in dynamically. It works perfect in the browser on my mac but it fails to work on an iphone or in the simulator. When you click the searchfield, the keyboard pops-up but when you start typing text, nothing gets entered in the textfield.

Here is my page-content with the listview

```html
<div id="woordenlijst_content" data-role="content" data-iscroll>
    <ul class="ul_woordenlijst_content" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Zoek...">
    </ul>
</div>
```

And this is how I load in the listitems

```js
$('#woordenlijst').live('pageinit', function(event) {
                  $.each(trefwoorden_array_sorted_nl, function(index, trefwoorden) {
                    $('.ul_woordenlijst_content').append('<li class="woord_nl" data-icon="arrow-r"><a id="opendialog_woordenlijst" class="woord_nl" selected-woord-nl="' + trefwoorden.nl +'" selected-woord-fr="' + trefwoorden.fr +'" audio="' + trefwoorden.sound + '">' + trefwoorden.nl + '</a></li>');
                  });
                  $('.ul_woordenlijst_content').listview('refresh');});
```

The listview is filled in perfectly, styles are being appended thanks to the refresh.
Scrolling works, the filterbar is on top... though when I try to enter text on an iphone, no text is being entered.

I have no clue what is wrong with it :-(

I'm using JQM 1.2.0
Phonegap Cordova 2.1.0

Comment: Nobody who has had the same problem or who has an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the sollution, well, for me at least.

When creating a cordova set-up for xcode a file index.css is generated.
in

```
* { }
```

find

```
-webkit-user-select: none;                  /* prevent copy paste, to allow, change 'none' to 'text' */
```

and remove this line.

It'll work.